# Would it be better to install XP on a mini laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, laptop

I have an HP mini laptop with Windows 7 Pro. It has an atom 1.6 N280 with 2G memory. It works a little slowly. If I install Windows-XP will it work faster? Can I get drivers for XP?

Comment: If you aren't opposed to a non-windows OS, Xubuntu would work wonderfully. As far as which windows version to choose, you probably won't notice much of a difference aside from the obvious functionality differences inside the OS.

Comment: My gosh, it is a 1.6ghz and 512 cache 667 FSB wanna be processor, how fast do you expect it to be? Posting your exact model may get you some more informed answers also....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?tmp_renderType=findModel&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c00033108

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While XP might work a little faster on that hardware. The difference should be noticeable, but not really significant. if you want a fast computer, don't get a netbook. They're meant for portability, not performance.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 for netbook is better than XP i found.
But the best OS I tested on my netbook was Ubuntu netbook edition, witch is the best if you don't mind leaving windows.

[Ubuntu netbook edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook) is made specially for netbook so it is fast and the display is optimized for netbooks too.

Good luck!

Comment: is Ubuntu is free ? and my program will work on hem (like office...winrar....) ?

Answer (score 1):

You might have trouble finding XP drivers for your netbook. I recommend you keep Win7 on it - or if you require more speed, then replace the netbook with a more powerful laptop or pc.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is that 2GB and below, go XP.  4GB and above, go 7 (64bit).  In between there, there's a lot of "it depends" involved.